# Understanding what makes a rule left-recursive in antlr

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4, left-recursion

I've been trial-and-erroring to figure out from an intuitive level when a rule in antlr is left-recursive of not. For example, this ([Removing left recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652060/removing-left-recursion))  is left-recursive in theory, but works in Antlr:

```
// Example input: x+y+1

grammar DBParser;

expression
    : expression '+' term
    | term;

term
    : term '*' atom
    | atom;

atom
    : NUMBER
    | IDENTIFIER
    ;

NUMBER              : [0-9]+        ;
IDENTIFIER          : [a-zA-Z]+     ;
```

[image]

So what makes a rule left-recursive **and a problem** in antlr4, and what would be the simplest example of showing that (in an actual program)? I'm trying to practice remove left-recursive productions, but I can't even figure out how to intentionally add a left-recursive rule that antlr4 can't resolve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antlr4 can handle direct left-recursion as long as it is not hidden:

- Hidden means that the recursion is not at the beginning of the right-hand side but it might still be at the beginning of the expansion because all previous symbols are nullable.
- Indirect means that the first symbol on the right-hand side of a production for `N` eventually derives a sequence starting with `N`. Antlr describes that as "mutual recursion".

Here are some SO questions I found by searching for `[antlr] left recursive`:

[ANTLR4 - Mutually left-recursive grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942414/antlr4-mutually-left-recursive-grammar)

[ANTLR4 mutually left-recursive error when parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460013/antlr4-mutually-left-recursive-error-when-parsing)

[ANTLR4 left-recursive error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100729/antlr4-left-recursive-error)

[ANTLR Grammar Mutually Left Recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47153634/antlr-grammar-mutually-left-recursive)

[Mutually left-recursive lexer rules on ANTL4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172053/mutually-left-recursive-lexer-rules-on-antl4)

[Mutually left recursive with simple calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982676/mutually-left-recursive-with-simple-calculator)

There are lots more, including one you asked. I'm sure you can mine some examples.

Comment: does `epsilon` just mean 'empty' when doing `A' → αA' | ε` ?

Comment: Yes, ε means nothing. It would be more accurate to write that as `A' → αA' |`, but many people prefer nothing to be visible; hence the ε. Nothing is a very hard concept; making nothing visible tends to make you think that it's something, but nothing is not something. It's nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by rici above, one of the items that Antlr4 does not support is indirect left-recursion. Here would be an example:

```
grammar DBParser;
expr: binop | Atom;
binop: expr '+' expr;
Atom: [a-z]+ | [0-9]+ ;
```

> `error(119): DBParser.g4::: The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [expr, binop]`

Notice that Antlr4 can support the following **direct** left-recursion though:

```
grammar DBParser;
expr: expr '+' expr | Atom;
Atom: [a-z]+ | [0-9]+ ;
```

However, even if you add in parentheticals (for whatever reason?) it doesn't work:

```
grammar DBParser;
expr: (expr '+' expr) | Atom;
Atom: [a-z]+ | [0-9]+ ;
```

Or:

```
grammar DBParser;
expr: (expr '+' expr | Atom);
Atom: [a-z]+ | [0-9]+ ;
```

Both will raise:

```
error(119): DBParser.g4::: The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [expr]
```

Comment: A parenthetical expression in the right-hand side of an Antlr rule is internally converted to a new non-terminal whose name doesn't appear anywhere in the grammar. So it effectively introduces indirectness (through the new non-terminal).

Comment: I could add that to the answer, if you think it would help.

Comment: @rici sure, or just copy into a new answer and I can delete mine -- whichever you prefer.